# Publish the last value of an observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I have a hot observable (a subject in this case):

```js
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
```

I want to create another observable that every time a new subscriptions is being made immediately fires out the last value that was produced.

So in pseudo code:

```js
var myObservableWithLastValue = subject.publishLast();

subject.onNext(3);

myObservableWithLastValue.subscribe(function(x){
    console.log(x); //should write 3
});

myObservableWithLastValue.subscribe(function(x){
    console.log(x); //should write 3, too
});

subject.onNext(4);

myObservableWithLastValue.subscribe(function(x){
    console.log(x); //should write 4
});
```

This is roughly what I want and it seems to work. However, I guess there must be some built in mechanism to achieve the same

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.keepLatest = function () {
    var latestValue;

    var disposable = this.subscribe(function (value) {
        latestValue = value;
    });

    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        observer.onNext(latestValue);
        return disposable.dispose;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 22):

RxJs now has the [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/679dee6a5819ec4a8c2af59bed3d1713589f99e5/src/core/subjects/replaysubject.js#L5). Initialize it with 1 buffer and you have the BehaviorSubject.

```js
// as an example, use buffer size of 2
var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(2 /* buffer size */);

subject.onNext('a');
subject.onNext('b');
subject.onNext('c');

subject.subscribe(function (x) { document.write('x1:' + x + '<br>'); });

subject.onNext('d');

subject.subscribe(function (x) { document.write('x2:' + x + '<br>'); });
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

Comment: @gajus-kuizinas Can you tell me what is the major difference between your code and the original? I'm afraid I'm missing something. Additionally, it sets the buffer size to 2 so the last 2 values will be replayed every time.

Comment: None. I just made the example interactive and complete. The buffer size is used to demonstrate difference from using `BehaviorSubject` in the @Asti answer. Thats the reason I did not create a new asnwer, but just contributed to yours.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Ok. I see your point. Improved a little more to show the results in the results window instead of console :)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `document.write` for this purpose. `console.log` allows to inspect and interact with the output. Thats opinion based suggestion, though.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas With console.log you can't see anything in the results window. Do you have any better suggestion? console.log is ok but not too interactive

Comment: It is by design that you cannot see anything in the browser window... because you can see everything in your Console window (dev tools).

Answer (score 7):

[BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md):

> Initializes a new instance of the `Rx.BehaviorSubject` class which creates a subject that caches its last value and starts with the specified value.

```js
var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('a' /* initial value */);

subject.subscribe(function (x) {
    console.log('x1:' + x);
});

subject.onNext('d');

// Will produce the last value.

subject.subscribe(function (x) {
    console.log('x2:' + x);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

Comment: Ok, but is there no built in operator that takes an existing stream and applies the sketched behaviour?

Comment: @Christoph Have you tried swapping your ordinary subject for a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: I'm not dealing with subjects directly. This was just to illustrate the behaviour better. I want an operator that applies on any hot infinite stream.

Comment: Subjects implement both IObserver<T> and IObservable<T>. You should be able to get the behaviour subject to subscribe to your IObservable and  then in turn Subscribe to the BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 0):

I have used `.cache(1)` on a hot `Observable`. Seems to give the behaviour you asked for (but I am a novice).

> observable that every time a new subscriptions is being made immediately fires out the last value that was produced.

Comment: FYI, my understanding is that `cache` has been [removed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2012) from the upcoming release.